# Hide/Show DataTemplate

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I have array of class Person in ViewModel and I want to show their names in table. I have also column with checkboxes. This is my View part:

```
 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="40">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox 
                            .........................
                            .... some logic here .... 
                            ......................./>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Width="140" 
                            Header="Name" 
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

How can I show/hide checkboxes column according to value of `IsSelectionAllowed` boolean variable.

Answer (score 1):

Use style:

```
    <Style x:Key="CheckBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelectionAllowed}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Attach with:

```
<CheckBox  Style="{StaticResource CheckBoxStyle}"
                        .........................
                        .... some logic here .... 
                        ......................./>
```

Comment: Did you put style to Resources?